# White space around paragraphs

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I'm having an issue with paragraphs. I got margin: 0, padding: 0; in all CSS but still got this weird whiet space around my text.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
 .advices_container_header span {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     }

     .advices_container_header p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
       }

      .advices_container_header_advices {
          display: block;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: Open Sans;
          font-size: 56px;
          color: rgba(255,96,0,1);
       }

       .advices_container_header_advices p {
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
        }

        .advices_container_header_text {
            display: block;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             font-family: Open Sans;
             font-size: 18px;
             color: rgba(107,107,107,1);
         }

         .advices_container_header_questionMark {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
             font-family: Open Sans;
             font-size: 48px;
             color: rgba(255,96,0,1);
          }
```

```html
   <div class="advices_container_header">   
                <p class="advices_container_header_advices">Wskazówki</p>
                <p class="advices_container_header_text">Jak przygotować się do przeprowadzki<span class="advices_container_header_questionMark">?</span></p>
            </div>
```

I got no problems with other text on the site, that's why this is weird to me.

Comment: I can see an image sort of thing above the text. It could be the margin of that element.

Comment: Please share you code in form of snippet so that, we can check. Besides that, the image is not clarifying your question very well. So please elaborate the question a lil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. Every line of text has a line-height:

> Line-height is the vertical distance between lines of text. On the
> web, it is an equal amount of space above and below text on a line.
>
> In CSS, the line-height property can take numeric or percentage
> values. If no line-height value is specified or inherited, the
> line-height by default is normal. It usually is about 20% larger than
> the font size.

So the right answer would be to set your line-height to 80%. However, for the font you gave in your example, it seems that 80% won't be enough. Depending on what you want to cut your next off it should be around 70-72% for your font.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.advices_container_header span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.advices_container_header p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.advices_container_header_advices {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 56px;
  color: rgba(255,96,0,1);
  line-height: 72%;
}

.advices_container_header_advices p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.advices_container_header_text {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(107,107,107,1);
}

.advices_container_header_questionMark {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: rgba(255,96,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="advices_container_header">  
  <p class="advices_container_header_advices">Wskazówki</p>
  <p class="advices_container_header_text">Jak przygotować się do przeprowadzki<span class="advices_container_header_questionMark">?</span></p>
</div>
```

If your intention is to use this as a logo. I recommend you use SVG images instead.

Comment: Ok, changing the line-height to 80% fixed this issue. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix it with line-height, but it properly defaults I'm guessing, also I'd use the * tag, and set padding and margin to 0, instead of copying it everywhere, the * tag targets all HTML elements btw.

Comment: I used the line-height and now it's quite better, but there is still some white space around.

Answer (score 1):

You can force line-height to be the same as your font-size and remove all redundant of margin, padding and font-family:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.advices_container_header_advices {
    display: block;
    font-size: 56px;
    line-height: 56px;
    color: rgba(255,96,0,1);
}

.advices_container_header_text {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: rgba(107,107,107,1);
}

.advices_container_header_questionMark {
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    color: rgba(255,96,0,1);
}
```

Comment: I used the line-height and now it's quite better, but there is still some white space around.

Comment: I used the line-height and now it's quite better, but there is still some white space around.